# How can i send data to a server from an offline webpage?

Tags: php, html

I am fairly uneducated on webpage / server side scripting, but have made a basic webpage for some course work. I have a user feedback style forms (asking for an email and the comment, a suggestion about a potential charity to promote). This webpage will, presumably, be run on a standard PC with access to the web, but it will not be uploaded (I.e. I'm sending the .HTML file to someone). How could I send information from the HTML forms to a free web-hosting server that I own? Thanks for any help, but please be noob friendly in your terminology!

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I'll hopefully have it all up-and-running in time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the computer that will run your webpage connected to Internet ?
If so, locate your form tag, and modify your html code to become something like this :

```
<form action="http://server.com/sendform.php">
```

For this to work you need to change the URL to fit your actual server, and have the php webpage use the data sent from the form to save it, but I suppose you already have that

Comment: I don't, sorry I wasn't clear in the question. How would I go about using php to interpret the data received? Also, I have never really looked into php coding, so know nothing of scripting in it. Thanks!

Comment: If you really don't know any coding, I suggest to you that you look into google forms, here's a small example I quickly put together : https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Wo9hsaEcPTR-ITNLllRHIpDuT2onaCzWNmftxl63WeQ/viewform

Answer (score 3):

The form is sent to the url of the action attribute:

```
<form action="http://yourserver.com/yourformhandler.php" ...>
    ...
</form>
```